# URL to H2 database in Openshift

Tags: openshift, h2

I have a H2 database running in its own pod in openshift. I am trying to figure out how to take my spring-boot app and connect it to my H2 container.

In my spring-boot app I have the following configuration in my `application.properties` folder:

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.profiles.active=h2
```

I have routes and a service set up for both the H2 and spring app. The route for the H2 is `http://database-h2-route-openshift.com` and is on port 1521. Just putting the URL in `application.properties` doesn't work

Comment: I am kind of looking for a similar solution, have you got this to working? Can you share your thoughts on how you did go about?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are these 2 pods in the same project? (i will continue this answer with the assumption that both pods are in the same project)
2. Ensure this service has the H2 pod listed in its list of pods.
3. You would not need a route here (if both pods are in the same project). you just need to specify the `service name` in the `spring.datasource.url`